# Google BigQuery group by sum and keep track of row numbers and IF condition on latest row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that I have some trouble getting right. I have a table with won sales deals. In that, I need to group by org_id, which is the client id and sum value of the deals, keep track of the row number ordered by won_time so I can see if the won_time of the latest won deal is more than a year or not and show that in the result.

This is how far I have come so far. The query works but returns a none aggregated result.

```
SELECT 
    org_id,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY won_time DESC) AS row_number,
    SUM(CAST(converted_value as NUMERIC)) as ltv
    IF(won_time < 'start_of_year', 'true', 'false') as status
FROM deals
WHERE status = 'won' AND row_number = 1
GROUP BY org_id, won_time, converted_value
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Added image with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT d.org_id,
        SUM(CAST(d.converted_value as NUMERIC)) as ltv
        (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(won_time)) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) as status
FROM deals d
GROUP BY org_id;
```

It seems to do what you describe.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff see the image I added in the description

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg . . . I think this query does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  org_id, 
  SUM(CAST(converted_value AS NUMERIC)) AS ltv,
  DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), MAX(won_time), YEAR) = 0 AS status
FROM `project.dataset.deals`
GROUP BY org_id
```

If to apply to sample data from  your question - result is

```
Row org_id  ltv status   
1   1       300 false    
2   2       500 true     
3   3       600 true     
4   4       300 false    
5   5       200 true
```